# How to share/stream an android tv screen to another device

Tags: android-tv, screen-sharing

Is that even possible? unfortunately most answers google gives me are about sharing a device content to a TV. I need to stream my TV's content to other devices, such that the content my TV is showing can be watched remotely (Something like sharing game content through twitch)

Comment: You mean to share the just the screen, or the media you have stored on your android tv?

Comment: just the screen, whatever is actually displayed on the screen